# React Dropzone to apply css on drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am working on react with Dropzone. my requirement is i do need to show Dropzone area a text like in the center when we drag files to drop area( text: you are inserting files) + a blue border in the drop area

my code looks like

```
  <Dropzone
    disableClick={true}
    className={styles.dropStyle}
    dropzoneActive={{ borderColor: 'green' }}
    onDrop={e => this.props.change(e)}
  >
    <div>...this is the dropzone area...</div>
   </DropZone>
```

Here border color green is not coming , its taking only dropStyle css+ plus i need to show a text inside the div only when we drag files to zone area.

I mean its a normal div with lot of assets, when we drop only css should apply( means dropzoneActive css should be visible )

Any fiddle will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using react-dropzone? Since [typings](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/master/typings/react-dropzone.d.ts) does not have a `className` and `dropzoneActive` prop I am wondering how you got that working. Anyway...

Here is some code I used for Dropzone

**React:**

```
                  <Dropzone
                    onDrop={// do stuff here}
                    accept='image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png'
                    multiple={true}
                  >
                    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => {
                      return (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          {
                            <p className='fileDrop'>
                              Try dropping one or more files here
                            </p>
                          }
                        </div>
                      );
                    }}
                  </Dropzone>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fileDrop {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px dashed #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fileDrop:hover {
  background: rgb(194, 243, 194);
  border: 1px dashed #333;
}
```

I see two ways to achive your goal.
1st is with css like render a div with class hidden and on hover you display the content.

```
                 <Dropzone
                    onDrop={// do stuff here}
                    accept='image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png'
                    multiple={true}
                  >
                    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => {
                      return (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          {
                            <p className='hidden-text'>
                              Try dropping one or more files here
                            </p>
                          }
                        </div>
                      );
                    }}
                  </Dropzone>

.hidden-text {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.hidden-text:hover {
  display: block or whatever
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

2nd is you write your own javascript event handler to render the text on hover.

Comment: <Dropzone className={styles.tabContent} disableClick>
            <div
              className= {styles.dropStyle}
              onDragEnter={e => this.props.styleChange( 'leave')}
              onDragOver={e => this.props.styleChange( 'over')}
              onDrop={e => this.props.change(e)}
            >

this works, on styleChange am just toggling a setState ,say am making styleChange to true on over and styleChange to false on leave . and on over am applying some css say am making some border to blue , but problem is am facing time delay on leave

Comment: something like this when i enter dropzone it should show blue color and when i leave dropzone it should show nothing (blue border should disappear)

Comment: could you share your code on codesandbox.io please?